# How to upgrade databse with deleting old database in flutter?

Tags: sql, flutter

I have some database in flutter, when I am trying to change version of database, I can't remove old. I know why this happening, I just have to write code of deleting database in onCreateFunc. What's the problem? I dunno how to do it. How can reach my goal?

> This my code:

```
class DBHelper {
  static Database db_instance;

  final String TABLE_NAME = "DatabaseModel";

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (db_instance == null) db_instance = await initDB();
    return db_instance;
  }

  initDB() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "maps_database.db");
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 3, onCreate: onCreateFunc);
    return db;
  }

  void onCreateFunc(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME'
        '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
        'realTime TEXT, '
        'moduleDate TEXT, '
        'moduleTime TEXT, '
        'moduleDay TEXT, '
        'gpsCoordinates TEXT, '
        'gpsSatellites TEXT, '
        'gpsTime TEXT, '
        'gpsDate TEXT, '
        'temperature TEXT, '
        'pressure TEXT, '
        'humidity TEXT, '
        'dust TEXT, '
        'zivert TEXT )');

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not delete the existing table and create a new table because it already exists with the same name. Try the following piece of code inside the function.

```sql
await db.execute('CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE $TABLE_NAME'
        '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
        'realTime TEXT, '
        'moduleDate TEXT, '
        'moduleTime TEXT, '
        'moduleDay TEXT, '
        'gpsCoordinates TEXT, '
        'gpsSatellites TEXT, '
        'gpsTime TEXT, '
        'gpsDate TEXT, '
        'temperature TEXT, '
        'pressure TEXT, '
        'humidity TEXT, '
        'dust TEXT, '
        'zivert TEXT )');

  }
```